# How to get max and min value of system variables from mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-python

I want to get min and max values of system variables from mysql(for version 5.6,5.7,8.0).

For example, server system variable `transaction_prealloc_size` is in range `[1024,131072]` and the default value is `4096`.

There are hundreds of variables and hard to get the min and max values of them from mysql manual document one by one.

Is there any convenient method that I can get the name/min/max/default/type(integer or enumerator or string) of system variables of mysql in batch?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?  tell us that; there may be some other way to solve it

Comment: Tuning mysql with Ottertune (cmu, github:https://github.com/cmu-db/ottertune). In this project, I need to specify the range of every knobs for normalization. The project presents the range for mysql5.6,5.7,8.0 but not applicable for mysql of the latest version. So I need to get the max/min etc information of these knobs in a convenient way.